# Using (x,y,z) coordinates information to animate 3D Character

Tags: animation, three.js, blender

I am using a handpose estimation model that uses the webcam to generate (x, y, z) coordinates for each joint from a moving hand (the z is estimated accurately). I also have a .glb character with a full T-bone skeleton structure, with hands, that is made using Blender.

What I cannot figure out is how to use these real-time data points to animate the imported 3D character’s hand in ThreeJS . The (x, y, z) is in 3D cartesian plane and from what I’ve read in the docs, ThreeJS uses Euler/Quaternion angles for rotation (correct me if I’m wrong). I’m at an impasse right now because I am unsure of how to convert this into angular data.

I am fairly new to animation so please do let me know if there are other libraries that can help me do this in an easier fashion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for inverse kinematics. It calculates variable joint parameters (angles or scales) depending on the end of the chain. The end of the chain i yours xyz position in space. The chain is arm for example. The joints are virtual joints of yours characters rig.